# Green Potassium Manganate and Sodium Hydroxide Equation

Tags: everyday-chemistry, redox, stoichiometry

When a sample of green potassium manganate (VI), $\ce{K2MnO4}$, is added to aqueous sodium hydroxide, a brown black solid A and a purple solution of B are obtained.

I know that the brown black solid A is $\ce{MnO2}$, but I can't seem to write out the entire equation.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks! Really appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the identity of B?

Comment: definitely a Mno4 ion, possibly NaMno4

Comment: Great, that's correct. To make balancing simpler, I suggest removing the spectator ions, or if you find that difficult, imagine for now that all alkali metal ions are the same type, for example using $\ce{KOH}$ instead of $\ce{NaOH}$. So put $\ce{K2MnO4}$ in the reagents, and $\ce{KMnO4}$ and $\ce{MnO2}$ in the products. On which side does the $\ce{KOH}$ go? Wherever you put it, notice that only one side will have hydrogen, and the equation cannot be balanced. What do you think is a reasonable compound to put on the other side that also contains hydrogen?

Comment: i managed to use half equations in basic sln to solve this question. Removed all the spectators

Comment: Showing your work by answering your own question is highly encouraged!

Comment: Yes! Please show what you have done! It'll be a great help for the answerer to know the best things to type when answering. And, welcome to chemistry.SE!

Answer (score 3):

$$\ce{ 3K2MnO4 + 2NaOH + 2H2O -> MnO2 +2NaMnO4 + 6KOH }$$

As you said the brown solid A is $\ce{MnO2}$ while the purple solution is due to the permanganate ion .